# Converting string representation of boxes into explicit boxes

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, boxes

It is very easy and convenient to write textual labels as `Strings` in the WYSIWYG mode. For example, I define a short form describing a linear model: `"2D3O"`, which means "two descriptors of type D and tree descriptors of type O". Everything is good so far. Now I wish to add superscripts and use standard palette to add them. I get

[image: screenshot]

Looks nice. But at some point I have a lot of such labels and wish to apply some formatting to all of them at once. For example, I wish to make all the digits `Bold` and all the letters `Gray`. `FullForm` shows internal structure and I see the [string representation of boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html):

[image: screenshot]

This is not a format easy to deal with. The tutorial explains how to convert ordinary boxes to its string representation using `ToString`. But what is the general way to convert string representation of boxes into explicit boxes?

Comment: Does `MakeBoxes@@ToHeldExpression@string` help?

Comment: @Simon It works with the example in question but fails with this: `"3\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(2\)]\)2O"`. `MakeBoxes` returns a box structure with redundant space character (representing multiplication produced by `ToHeldExpression`).

Comment: Generally speaking, `ToExpression` is very fragile way to convert string representation of boxes because it requires syntactically correct expression inside of the string.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: I mean that formatted string should look as original in the sence of the spacings between characters (and there are not additional spacings in my examples).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Those are not spacings but the way `FE` is interpreting such expression. I don't know how to fight this without decomposing everythig. Take a look at `StringForm["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(````\), \(``\)]\)", 
 Style["R", Gray], Style[3, Bold], Style[1, Bold]]`

Comment: @Kuba Conversion of string representation of boxes into explicit boxes is a kind of task which one expect to be implemented by WRI. I hope it is implemented but I failed to find any built-in way. Implementing this is probably not a fun considering [Jonh Fultz's comments](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/xp4fuxv_ODk/tOqGkuy3RWgJ).

Comment: @Kuba Your new approach works very well with my current set of labels (+1).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov uff, great :) and thanks for motivation to read about this syntax :)

Comment: The Wolfram Function Repository has an entry for this now. ```ResourceFunction["StringToBoxes"]```. The [docs](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/StringToBoxes) provide some good example usage.

Answer (score 4):

#### Conversion to explicit boxes:

```
ClearAll[expr, myStyle, string];
expr = ("\!\(" ~~ Longest[Except["\!"]] .. ~~ "\)");
plain = (Except[{"\*", "\)"}] ..);


myStyle[string_] := StringReplace[string, {       
 x : DigitCharacter :> "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"" <> x <> "\", FontColor -> RGBColor[1,0,0]]\)",
 x : LetterCharacter :> "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"" <> x <> "\", FontColor -> RGBColor[0,0,1]]\)"}]

format[string_] := Map[
 If[StringTake[#, 1] == "\!",
    ToExpression[StringReplace[#, "\(" ~~ x : plain ~~ "\)" :> "\(\"" <> x <> "\"\)"]],
    #] &,
 StringSplit[string, x : expr :> x]
   ] /. x_String :> myStyle[x] // Row
```

> [image]

---

#### Unfinished pure string approach:

```
ClearAll[expr, myStyle, boxFormat, scanner];
expr = ("\!\(" ~~ Longest[Except["\!"]] .. ~~ "\)");

myStyle[string_] := StringReplace[string, {       
 x : DigitCharacter .. :> "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"" <> x <> "\", FontWeight -> Bold]\)", 
 x : LetterCharacter .. :> "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"" <> x <> "\", FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.5`]]\)"}]

boxFormat[string_] := StringReplace[string, 
   "\(" ~~ x : (Except["\*"] ~~ __) ~~ "\)" :> "\(" <> myStyle[x] <> "\)"];

scanner = If[StringTake[#, 1] == "\!", boxFormat@#, myStyle@#] &;
```

Usage:

```
string = "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(D3\), \(1\)]\) 1 \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(1\)]\)"

scanner /@ StringSplit[string, x : expr :> x] // StringJoin
```

> [image]
>
> [image]