# How to recover these TemplateBox into normal form?

Tags: front-end, formatting, conversion, boxes, input-forms

I often use $\TeX$ editor by <kbd>Insert</kbd>→<kbd>Inline TeX Input</kbd> in `PlotLabel` to label graphics:

[image]

I will get a well-formed plot label:

[image]

But when I *Copy As Input Text* and paste it into StackExchange, it will be:

```
Plot[Sin[3 x], {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "\!\(\*TemplateBox[<|\"boxes\" -> FormBox[\nRowBox[{\"sin\", \"(\", \
\nRowBox[{\"3\", \nStyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"]}], \")\"}], \
TraditionalForm], \"errors\" -> {}, \"input\" -> \"\\\\sin(3x)\", \
\"state\" -> \"Boxes\"|>,\n\"TeXAssistantTemplate\"]\)"]
```

Actually this code is still valid, but it's **ugly**.  Can we recover this `TemplateBox` into **normal form for re-editing**?

Comment: It should be mentioned that this functionality was added in version 12.2 or thereabouts. I don't have it in version 12.0

Comment: Two questions. 1. Why do you have the label inside of quotes? 2. What is the normal form you are expecting (is it sin(3x)?).

Comment: @MarcoB Idon't very sure this is introduced in which version

Comment: @CarlWoll 1, Sometimes mma will rearrange my label expression if without that quotes. 2, The normal form mean it's not included that ugly `TemplateBox` things but is a simple $sin(3x)$ like the arrow pointed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you want to edit the box expressions**, there're already some similar questions on MSE, such as [47213](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47213/converting-string-representation-of-boxes-into-explicit-boxes), [13317](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13317/how-can-i-get-the-unchanged-box-form-of-an-arbitrary-expression).

##### Solution 1

However, the direct use of `` FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket `` makes my kernel hang up (perhaps because the front-end can't handle the `TeXAssistant` box in such a way), so I use the following workaround:

```
FrontEndExecute[
  FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[
    "\!\(TemplateBox[<|\"boxes\" -> FormBox[\nRowBox[{\"sin\", \"(\", \nRowBox[{\"3\", \nStyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"]}], \")\"}], TraditionalForm], \"errors\" -> {}, \"input\" -> \"\\\\sin(3x)\", \"state\" -> \"Boxes\"|>,\n\"TeXAssistantTemplate\"]\)"
  , True]
][[1]] //ToExpression
(* Output: TemplateBox[<|"boxes" ->     FormBox[RowBox[{"sin", "(", RowBox[{"3", StyleBox["x", "TI"]}],        ")"}], TraditionalForm], "errors" -> {}, "input" -> "\\sin(3x)",    "state" -> "Boxes"|>, "TeXAssistantTemplate"] *)
```

> Note: two characters `\*` have been removed from the string!

##### Solution 2

Or simply use the kernel function:

```
ToExpression@"\!\(TemplateBox[<|\"boxes\" -> FormBox[\nRowBox[{\"sin\", \"(\", \nRowBox[{\"3\", \nStyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"]}], \")\"}], TraditionalForm], \"errors\" -> {}, \"input\" -> \"\\\\sin(3x)\", \"state\" -> \"Boxes\"|>,\n\"TeXAssistantTemplate\"]\)"
(* Output: TemplateBox[<|boxes->FormBox[RowBox[{sin,(,RowBox[{3,StyleBox[x,TI]}],)}],TraditionalForm],errors->{},input->\sin(3x),state->Boxes|>,TeXAssistantTemplate] *)
```

> Note: two characters `\*` have been removed from the string!

##### Solution 3

Or use this kernel function, which has the capacity to convert string box representations as a part of its functionality:

```
BoxForm`ConvertForm["\!\(\*TemplateBox[<|\"boxes\" -> FormBox[\nRowBox[{\"sin\", \"(\", \nRowBox[{\"3\", \nStyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"]}], \")\"}], TraditionalForm], \"errors\" -> {}, \"input\" -> \"\\\\sin(3x)\", \"state\" -> \"Boxes\"|>,\n\"TeXAssistantTemplate\"]\)", StandardForm, StandardForm][[1, 1]]
(* Output: RowBox[{"Sin", "[", RowBox[{"3", " ", "x"}],      "]"}] *)
```

---

**If you want a `TeXAssistant` box comes back in the notebook**, you can use `NotebookWrite` to write it.

##### Solution 1: Button

```
Button["Click to replace selected string!",
  NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[],
    ToExpression@StringReplace[StartOfString~~"\!\(\*"~~s__~~"\)"~~EndOfString:>s]@ToExpression@NotebookRead@EvaluationNotebook[]
  ]
]
```

##### Solution 2: Define the format of a wrapping symbol

Evaluate this line:

```
wrapper /: MakeBoxes[wrapper@str_?StringQ, _] := ToExpression@StringReplace[StartOfString~~"\!\(\*"~~s__~~"\)"~~EndOfString:>s]@str
```

then add a head to the box string, like this:

```
wrapper@"\!\(\*TemplateBox[<|\"boxes\" -> FormBox[\nRowBox[{\"sin\", \"(\", \nRowBox[{\"3\", \nStyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"]}], \")\"}], TraditionalForm], \"errors\" -> {}, \"input\" -> \"\\\\sin(3x)\", \"state\" -> \"Boxes\"|>,\n\"TeXAssistantTemplate\"]\)"
```

then select these code, click the menu command `Cell/Convert To/StandardForm` (or simply press the hot key `Shift+Ctrl+N`)

##### Solultion 3: Add a menu command

Evaluate the following:

```
FrontEndUtilities`Action["BuildBoxFromString"] := NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[],
  ToExpression@StringReplace[StartOfString~~"\!\(\*"~~s__~~"\)"~~EndOfString:>s]@ToExpression@NotebookRead@EvaluationNotebook[]
]
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["AboutBoxDialog", {
  Delimiter,
  MenuItem["BuildBoxFromString",
    KernelExecute@FrontEndUtilities`Action["BuildBoxFromString"],
    MenuKey["F4", Modifiers -> {"Control"}]
, MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]
}]
```

Then you can use a menu command with a hotkey to replace selected string by the box represented by it. The menu option will be placed after the item `Help/About Mathematica`.

You can add the code above to `init.m` for automatic evaluation.

Comment: The code [work for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k60aa.png)?

Comment: @yode Yes, I got `TemplateBox[<|"boxes" -> 
   FormBox[RowBox[{"sin", "(", RowBox[{"3", StyleBox["x", "TI"]}], 
      ")"}], TraditionalForm], "errors" -> {}, "input" -> "\\sin(3x)",
   "state" -> "Boxes"|>, "TeXAssistantTemplate"]` and `BoxData[{RowBox[{"Sin", "[", RowBox[{"3", " ", "x"}], 
    "]"}]}, StandardForm]`. I'm using 12.2.0.

Comment: @yode Note: you may not get the expected result if you haven't remove the `\*` in the string, which ask the front-end instead of the kernel for interpretting the box.

Comment: I hope those `TemplateBox` recover to the rendering style and when I click it I can re-edit it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep9SV.png). Is it possible?

Comment: @yode That's possible. I'll make an edit later.

Comment: Crazy man!! You have solved a problem that has been bothering me for a long time... I will give the bounty to you [after 21h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UAn8.png). And your current Solution 3 maybe will eat my quotation marks

Comment: @yode The front-end is possible to be understood and customized, usually more things can be under people's control than they have expected.

Comment: Does your answer mean that you can make this function into the menu options? Can you try it, please? I need this transformation every day.

Comment: @yode I updated the post to provide two solutions for long-term use.

Comment: I note I will lose my quotation marks after conversion?

Comment: @yode could you provide an example?

Comment: Note [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa3mp.png)

Comment: In this expression(`Uncompress[
 FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JtD7.png"], 
    "Byte"]]]]`), I will get [an error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsTZS.png) after conversion

Comment: @yode you can use `PlotLabel->ToString@...`

Comment: To perform box->string conversion while strictly keeping the box structure, return `RowBox@{"\"", oldResult,"\""}` instead of `oldResult`.